# MySQL - Using select statement within CASE-> when construct

Tags: mysql

The query looks like below:

```
SELECT apninfo.zip,
   CASE apninfo.zip
    WHEN (SELECT zip F
          FROM zipcode, apninfo
          WHERE zipcode.zip = apninfo.zip
         ) THEN "SD"
    WHEN (apninfo.zip > 9001 AND apninfo.zip < 96162) THEN "CA"
    ELSE "US"
  END AS LATION
FROM apinfo;
```

At first it tries to lookup zipcode table to see if the zip code is in San Diego. If not, there is check for CA. Else it assumes it is a US zip code.

MySQL throws an error. Can you please help?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: So all the `zip` in `zipcode` are those of San Diego?  Also, 9001 seems not to be a valid California starting point, as most US zip codes fall between 9001 and 96162.

Comment: Actually, they are mostly from san diego but some are outside san diego. I am going by the zip code listing provided by http://www.structnet.com/instructions/zip_min_max_by_state.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you could do something like that (I'm not like Michael B., I must admit I have no idea about US zip codes, so just taking that from your query).

```
select a.zip,
case when z.zip is not null then 'SD'
     when a.zip between 9001 and 96162 then 'CA'
     else 'US'
     end as location
FROM apinfo a
left join zipcode z on z.zip = a.zip
```